# Exit traffic through a SOCKS proxy

Tags: exit-relays, socks

I want to run an exit node, but don't want to risk having to deal with rouge DMCA complaints. I also have (pay for) a high-bandwidth SOCKS5 proxy. I would like to route all exit traffic from my node through this proxy; this will also let me set a less restrictive exit policy.

Is there any way to do this easily? I've looked at torrc options, and it seems like the Socks5Proxy option *nearly* does what I want, but doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There's no mechanism for this in Tor, you'll need to deal with routing the outbound traffic yourself.

You should also note that the address your relay is listening/running on will be linked to the address that you exit from, it will be observed by [CollecTor's TorDNSEL](https://collector.torproject.org/#exit-lists) and distributed in the list of Tor Exits.